# Some thing does not work at regionprops in matlab, why?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to find the centers of a formless bright spot but similar to circle in dark background for some specific images. When I use the `regionprops` with `'centroid'` in MATLAB for 109 images, I expect to have a struct that has 109 field and x,y coordinate of each spots centers , but I see just a `18*1` struct, so what is the problem?

What is the different between `regionpropse(bw,'centroid')` and `[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(...,...)` ? which one is accurate?

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

This is my code:

```
    clc;
    close all;
    clear all;

    numer_of_imgs=109;


    x = zeros(1,numer_of_imgs);
    y = zeros(1,numer_of_imgs);
    z = zeros(1,numer_of_imgs);
difz = zeros(1,numer_of_imgs);
img_2=imread('E:\Hand-king\MATLAB CODE\Pattern\Image\profilometer\0.96mm  \long_dist_for_2inch_testplate\long1\background\b.png');
img_2=im2bw(img_2,0.5);
img_2 = imcrop(img_2,[21 124 670 300]);

 for i=1:numer_of_imgs

im_new=imread([num2str(i),'.png']);
im_new = imcrop(im_new,[21 124 670 300]);

imbw1 = im2bw(im_new,0.3);

imbw1 =imbw1-img_2;
imbw1 = im2bw(imbw1,0.9);


%imshow(imbw1)

%     [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(imbw1,[9   25],'ObjectPolarity','bright');
%     viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','r');
%
%     x(i) = centers(1);
%     y(i) = centers(2);
%     z(i) = sqrt((x(i)-x(1))^2+(y(i)-y(1))^2);
%


s  = regionprops(imbw1, 'Centroid');
CenterMass = [s.Centroid];
x(i) = CenterMass(:,1);
y(i) = CenterMass(:,2);
z(i) = sqrt((x(i)-x(1))^2+(y(i)-y(1))^2);
z(i) = (z(i)/6)*0.01;


end
```

Comment: We need to see the image.  We can't reconstruct your problem with it

Comment: I added two images that use in the for loop(i =1).

Comment: @abolfazltavakoli Just add the image links to your question. Someone with enough rep will replace them with the actual images for you.

Comment: I add two images, one of them is the main image that named in code as im_new and other is the background that named as  img_2. By these images you can run the code for i=1.

Comment: I want to find center of the bright spot that shown in the image  , is there any body to advise me an accurate method?